# Affect of local_work_size on performance and why it is

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

Hello Everyone....
  i am new to opencl and trying to explore more @ it.

What is the work of local_work_size in openCL program and how it matters in performance.

I am working on some image processing algo and for my openCL kernel i gave 
as

```
size_t local_item_size = 1; 
size_t global_item_size = (int) (ceil((float)(D_can_width*D_can_height)/local_item_size))*local_item_size; // Process the entire lists
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and for same kernel when i changed

```
 size_t local_item_size = 16;
```

keeping everything same.

i got around 4-5 times faster performance.

Comment: You can set local_item_size to NULL; and OpenCL will choose the "best" size for work-group.But it does not take into account the local memory used.

Answer (score 6):

The **local-work-size**, aka **work-group-size**, is the number of **work-items** in each **work-group**.

Each work-group is executed on a **compute-unit** which is able to handle a bunch of work-items, not only one.

So when you are using too small groups you waste some computing power, and only got a coarse parallelization at the compute-unit level.

But if you have too many work-items in a group you can also lose some opportunnity for parallelization as some compute-units may not be used, whereas other would be overused.

So you could test with many values to find the best one or just **let OpenCL pick a good one** for you by passing **NULL** as the local-work-size.

PS : I'll be interested in knowing the peformance with OpenCL choice compared to your previous values, so could you please make a test and post the results.
Thanks :)

Comment: this is quite interesting.... so should i keep the local-work-size=(number of processing element in one COMPUTE UNIT). also i will post the result soon.

Comment: It's not a good idea.If you use a CPU, you can have only one processing element per compute unit.So you will have work group size=1.It's time consuming.
Generally, the recommended work-group size for kernels is 64-128 work-items.
Without considering the use of local memory. You should set the work group size like something like this:to Global_size/Compute Unit
You can get the preferred work group size multiple with CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE by calling to clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.
And, to benefit from using the vectorization on CPU,the work-group size must be a multiple of 8.