# OpenCL benchmark - advice about parameters to vary

Tags: opencl, benchmarking, reduction

I would like to perform runtime benchmark about the two-stage Sum reduction with OpenCL ( from this [AMD link](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/)) on a radeon HD 7970 Tahiti XT.

Initially, I took a first version of code where I didn't use the first loop which performs a reduction from an input array of size `N` to an output array of size `NworkItems`. Here's this first loop into kernel code :

```
  int global_index = get_global_id(0);
  float accumulator = 0;
  // Loop sequentially over chunks of input vector
  while (global_index < length) {
    float element = buffer[global_index];
    accumulator += element;
    global_index += get_global_size(0);
  }
```

So with this first version, I have measured the runtime as a function of input array size (which is equal to the total number of threads) and for different sizes of work group. Here's the results :

[image]

Now, I would like to do a benchmark where I use this initial loop above. But I don't know which parameters that I have to vary.

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254194/optimal-local-global-worksizes-in-opencl), one says that AMD recommends a multiple of 64 for the size of a WorkGroup (32 for NVIDIA).

Moreover, from last comment on [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761191/affect-of-local-work-size-on-performance-and-why-it-is/13762847#13762847), it is recommended to  set the work group size like : `WorkGroup size = (Number of total threads) / (Compute Units)`.
On my GPU card, I have 32 compute units.

So I would like to get advices for knowing which parameters would be interesting to vary in order to compare runtimes in this second version (with the first reduction loop). For example, I may take different values for the ratio `(N size of input array) / (total NworkItems)` and a fixed value for `WorkGroup size` (see expression above),

or do on the contrary, i.e should I vary the value for `WorkGroup size` and fix the ratio `(N size of input array) / (total NworkItems)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sum local data instead of spread out data, to aid memory transfer (coalesced data access). So use this instead:

```
  int chunk_size = length/get_global_size(0)+(length%get_global_size(0) > 0); //Will give how many items each work item needs to process
  int global_index = get_group_id(0)*get_local_size(0)*chunk_size + get_local_id(0); //Start at this address for this work item
  float accumulator = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<chunk_size; i++)
    // Loop sequentially over chunks of input vector
    if (global_index < length) {
      float element = buffer[global_index];
      accumulator += element;
      global_index += get_local_size(0);
    }
  }
```

Also you should use sizes that are powers of two, to help caching.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand well, I have to vary only two parameters : first "length" of input array and then "get_local_size(0)" = "size of each workGroup". So I could vary the same parameters that I used for generating the figure above of my first benchmark.

Comment: The problem with your code is that work item0 is reading scattered data from `buffer[]` separated by `global_size()`. Depending on the work item sizes, that may lead to a very bad memory pattern. It is better if each work group works on a small piece of the buffer, therefore caching works much better, and even all the work items in the group can share the cache.

Comment: with a given "WorkGroup size", do you advise me to take "Number of total threads = (WorkGroup size) * (Compute Units)" for my benchmark (with Compute Units = 32 on my GPU card and Compute Units = 8 on my CPU) ?